# Нужно вытащить из базы данных все строки, имеющие нужное слово

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

У меня есть база данных с таблицей, где содержится нужная информация. Мне необходимо достать из этой базы данных строки, где есть определённое слово, в моём случае это логин пользователя.
Я добился того, что бы выдавалась одна, нужная мне, строка, но мне нужны вообще все строки имеющие нужный логин пользователя. При попытке запросить ещё раз нужные мне строки, выдаётся всё та же строка.

```
<?php
    $mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'bob', '5555555559Ba', 'reg-users');
    $result = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `bron` WHERE `logins` LIKE '$login'"); // Получение нужной мне строки
    $result2 = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `bron` WHERE `logins` LIKE '$login'"); // Попытка получения второй строки, но безуспешно...
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc();
    $time = array_slice($row, 1, 1); /* Тут я вытаскиваю из массива по одной переменной,
так как они мне нужны по отдельности, что бы удобно вставить в таблицу. */
    $pc = array_slice($row, 2, 1);
    $adres = array_slice($row, 3, 1);
    $date = array_slice($row, 4, 1);
    $_SESSION["time"]=implode("",$time); /* Единственный понятый мною метод, как вывести на экран
нужную мне переменную. */
    $_SESSION["pc"]=implode("",$pc);
    $_SESSION["adres"]=implode("",$adres);
    $_SESSION["date"]=implode("",$date);
?>
```

Comment: А сам запрос в БД сколько строк возвращает?

Comment: Это делается одним запросом и перемещением по результату с помощью fetch-методов. Вот [пример](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php#refsect1-mysqli-result.fetch-assoc-examples)

Comment: @SwaD Одну строку

Comment: Если в самой БД есть только одна строка под заданные условия фильтрации, то откуда и как вы хотите получить вторую строку?

Comment: @u_mulder Спасибо за подсказку, но я не особо разбираюсь в этом, особенно в fetch-методах. Однако, благодаря тому, что вы скинули, у меня получилось выдавить несколько строк, однако теперь проблема с количеством переменных в этих строках. А точнее мне нужно вывести из базы данных, условно, 4 переменные со строки. Код выдаёт мне все нужные строки, но лишь первые две переменные этих строк...

Comment: @SwaD Простите, значит не правильно понял ваш вопрос. Подходящих по условиям фильтрации строк в базе данных 3, однако код выдаёт мне одну строку из них

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы неправильно используете функцию LIKE. Либо вы вообще не совсем понимаете как работать с SQL базами данных.

Предположим что у вас в переменной $login некая строка, по которой делается поиск.

Пусть для примера это будет строка *example*

Если у вас в таблице несколько завписей у которых в поле **logins** есть только значение *example*, то как правильно заметили в комментариях, нцжно в цикле получать данные для каждой строки. И в данном случае LIKE можно не использовать.

Т.е. будет как-то так

```
   $result = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `bron` WHERE `logins` = '$login'");     
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      print_r($row);
   }
```

Если же в поле **logins** у вас значения содержат строки в которых нужная строка *example* входит как подстрока, то тут уже нужно использовать LIKEб и использовать wildcards.

В этом случае запрос к базе будет, например, такой

```
$result = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `bron` WHERE `logins` LIKE '%$login%'");
```

Здесь знаки процента (%) это wildcards и они обозначают любое число символом. В данном случае любое число символов до искомой строки и любое число символов после.

А дальше чтобы обработать все строки точно так же цикл по всем строкам, которые вернул запрос.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение. Я действительно не особо знаком с SQL базами данных. Я исправил, как вы и написали. Всё заработало как надо. Странно, такой код у меня был до моих поисков по интернету и он не выдавал то, что нужно... Возможно я накосячил где-то, однако теперь всё работает, спасибо!